# JQuery div.height is wrong in Chrome to make all the divs same height

Tags: css, jquery, document-ready, window-load

I have used the following code to have equal height for `rightpos`, `leftpos` and `middlepos` divs:

```
<script>

    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        // Find the greatest height:
        maxHeight = Math.max($('#rightpos').height(), $('#middlepos').height());
        maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $('#leftpos').height());

        // Set height:
        $('#rightpos').height(maxHeight);
        $('#middlepos').height(maxHeight);
        $('#leftpos').height(maxHeight);

    })
</script>
```

Determining of the tallest div using this way for the main page of http://yaskawa.ir/ works well in Firefox, but has problems in Chrome.

---

**UPDATE 1** after **Sparky672**'s answer:

I can see that with this code,the `alert('test here');` at the end doesn't work.

```
<script>
    jQuery.noConflict();
    //jQuery(document).ready(function($){});

    jQuery(window).load(function($){

        // Find the greatest height:
        maxHeight = Math.max($('#rightpos').height(), $('#middlepos').height());
        maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $('#leftpos').height());

        // Set height:
        $('#rightpos').height(maxHeight);
        $('#middlepos').height(maxHeight);
        $('#leftpos').height(maxHeight);

        alert('test here');
    })
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: I see all the div's with the same height (using Chrome). What's the problem?

Comment: I'm using chromium in Linux and it has the problem. I'll upload the pic now

Comment: Please construct jsFiddle of your problem.  `window.load` is working fine here:  http://jsfiddle.net/snBLP/3/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try `window.load()` in place of `document.ready()` to ensure that all assets are loaded before your heights are calculated.

```
jQuery(window).load(function($){
```

Documentation:

> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have
>   been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element
>   associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the
>   window object.

http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

See DEMO:

http://jsfiddle.net/snBLP/3/

Comment: Thank you @Sparky672, but it didn't work and it seems that this corrupted my code. The `alert` at the end doesn't work.

Comment: @smhnaji, [there is nothing unusual in my answer](http://jsfiddle.net/snBLP/2/).  Scroll down [this page and see first example code](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/).  Can you construct a jsFiddle demo to show your problem?

Comment: it's very strange but when using `jQuery(window).load`, I saw that `$` doesn't work (while `document.ready` worked EXACTLY with the `$` and the same code), anyway I used `jQuery` instead of `$` with your solution. The live example is at the main page of http://yaskawa.ir/

Answer (score -2):

$(document).ready() isn't suitable for calculating heights. $(document).ready() doesn't wait for images to load, etc.

I'd suggest trying

```
$(window).ready()
```

instead...

Comment: Can you please give me my points back Sparky? I've personally used $(window).ready()...and it's just as good as $(window).load()

Comment: You may think it works great, but it is not the same thing at all, and your answer is not much different than `document.ready`.  Again, read the documentation for `.ready()`... _"Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded."_.  Whereas, `.load()` _"is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded."_